# Align Field RIGHT not working when using CheckBoxField

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to align a **CheckBoxField** and **TextField** on LEFT and RIGHT respectively using an **HorizontalFieldManager**. But unfortunately the TextField is never visible.

I tried the same code with two buttons, and the buttons were visible without any trouble (one button on the right corner and the other on the left corner of the screen).

But I am not sure, why I can't acheive the same if I use a CheckBoxField. Here is my code,

```java
checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager=new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
keepLoggedCheckboxField=new CheckboxField("keep Me Logged In", true,CheckboxField.FIELD_LEFT);

forgotPasswordTextField=new TextField(TextField.FIELD_RIGHT);
forgotPasswordTextField.setText("Forgot Password?");
checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager.add(keepLoggedCheckboxField);
checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager.add(forgotPasswordTextField);
add(checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager);
```

[image: Screenshot]

I even tried reducing the text length on both the fields. But still the same issue.

Comment: create a new horizontal field manager with field as left and add the checkbox on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's two problems here.

### Field Alignment

The problem is that a `HorizontalFieldManager` does not use the `FIELD_RIGHT` flag you're setting on the text field.  `HorizontalFieldManager` just lays out fields left to right as you add them. [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4184300/119114).

You can solve this problem a couple ways.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10185954/119114) for two solutions.

### TextField Width

I believe the `TextField` is also taking up all available width by default, and it lays out its text on the left side of the field, by default.  So, *only* solving the field alignment problem won't be enough.  You can fix this either of two ways:  make the `TextField` draw its text right-aligned, or shrink the width of the `TextField` to just barely fit the text.

For the first solution, you can see a sample blog post [I added here](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/justifying_text_in_a_blackberry).

For the second solution, you can override `Field#layout()` in the `TextField` class.  That solution, combined with one field alignment solution, might look like this:

```java
checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
keepLoggedCheckboxField = new CheckboxField("keep Me Logged In", true, CheckboxField.FIELD_LEFT);
checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager.add(keepLoggedCheckboxField);

forgotPasswordTextField = new TextField(TextField.FIELD_RIGHT) {
    protected void layout(int w, int h) {
        super.layout(w, h);
        Font f = getFont();
        setExtent(getPaddingLeft() + f.getAdvance(getText()) + getPaddingRight(), 
                getPaddingTop() + f.getHeight() + getPaddingBottom());
    }
};
forgotPasswordTextField.setText("Forgot Password?");

VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
vfm.add(forgotPasswordTextField);

checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager.add(vfm);
add(checkBoxHorizontalFieldManager);
```